# I want to print a column's value from a table using id generated from another table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

[image: First table]

[image: second table]

I want to print the names of top three trending tags (the one that are used the most). 
In order to get the trending **tags id** I used this query which is working

```
DB::table('review_tag')->select('tag_id')->groupBy('tag_id')->orderBy(DB::raw('count(tag_id)'), 'desc')->take(3)->get();
```

Now I need to get the names of the tags from a table **tags** using the **id** I got from **review_tag** table using above query

I tried using this but it didn't work

```
B::table('review_tag')->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'review_tag.tag_id')->select('tags.name')->groupBy('tag_id')->orderBy(DB::raw('count(tag_id)'), 'desc')->take(3)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the result of your first query in a second like:

```
$results = ... first query

B::table('tags')->select('name')->whereIn('id', $results->toArray())->get();
```

Comment: "PHP error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" This is the error I'm getting. Can you please help?